# Is it possible to pass parameters dynamically to a TestNG function and use it in a parallel execution?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am working on selenium chrome webdriver and i want to pass an ArrayList to the function and use its out put on a parallel execution and different sessions.
For example `SupportItems` class contains an ArrayList of proxies and i want to use each proxy in a single session.

This is my code:

```java
public class ParallelExecution {

    public static final  int invocationCount = 5;
    private static final String driverPath = ".\\drivers\\";

    @Test(threadPoolSize = invocationCount, invocationCount = invocationCount)
    public static void parallelExecution(ArrayList<SupportItems> items) throws InterruptedException {

        GetExternalInfos getInfos = new GetExternalInfos();
        items = new ArrayList<SupportItems>(getInfos.getInputs());

        WebDriver chromeDriver =  null;
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = null; 

        chromeOptions= new ChromeOptions();

        // Set the pre defined capability – ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS value to true
        chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");

        // Disable Automation Extention
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));    

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  driverPath + "chromedriver.exe");
        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

        chromeDriver.get("https://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

And this is my testNG.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
  <test name="SupportTest" >
    <classes>
      <class name="windowbuilder.view.ParallelExecution"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- SupportTest -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: why dont you want to use DataProvider and pass your values in xml file?

Comment: @Vault23 because the values will be passed through GUI interface by the user.